# AndroidTest Resource Folder in Bitrise

Tags: android, android-testing, ui-testing, bitrise

I'm configuring a workflow in Bitrise to run my instrumentation tests for an Android project. I don't know why but the AndroidTest resource directory is not available during Bitrise ui tests. I have this in my `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            resources.srcDirs += ['src/AndroidTest/assets']
        }
    }
```

and I'm doing this to load the assets from my tests:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

This is working smoothly locally but in Bitrise the assets are not found. Any idea about this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to do a new git clone of this repository into a new directory? Most of the times the reason for "it works locally but not on Bitrise" is that you have some file(s) locally which aren't in the repository and so are not available on Bitrise after the git clone. If that wouldn't help please contact bitrise support via onsite chat or email, as without more details it's incredibly hard to tell what can be the issue, but our support team can guide you through debugging :)

Comment: @ViktorBenei Thanks for your help, the folder was included in the repo, but I don't know why it wasn't included inside the test apk. I posted a new answer with a workaround for it and now is working smoothly in bitrise :)

Comment: Glad to hear and thanks for sharing @rdiaz82 ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to solve the problem. Instead of add the resources inside `src/AndroidTest/assets` I created a new assets folder just for the debug build variant:

[image]

In this case, I don't need anymore to add the assets as an additional folder because it will be already included inside the test apk. Using the debug build variant this folder will not be included inside the release apk so this solution works fine for me.

The only difference is that now in order to load the resources I need to do it through the context inside my test in the following way:

`InputStream inputStream = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getAssets().open("mock/" + filename);`